# Usage of as well as

Tags: grammar

> The FDA is increasing stakeholder communications related to biosimilars, including timely guidance for sponsors in order to provide scientific and regulatory predictability, as well as more efficient structures to support the development and review of biosimilar and interchangeable products. This includes efforts to harmonize international regulation of biosimilars and the acceptance of non-U.S. comparator products, **as well as** greater use of real-world data supporting regulatory decision making related to biosimilars.[FDA](https://www.fda.gov/ucm/groups/fdagov-public/@fdagov-drugs-gen/documents/document/ucm613761.pdf)

Hi,
What is paralled with "greater use" here?
I think:

This includes (1) efforts to harmonize international regulations ... and the acceptance, (2) as well as greater use of...

or is it

This includes (1) efforts to harmonize international regulations... (2) and the acceptance, (3) as well as greater use of...?

And regarding "as well as", if I want to parallelize 3 nouns, should I put "and"?

i.e. A, B, as well as C vs A **and** B, as well as C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This includes (1) efforts to harmonize international regulations ... and the acceptance, (2) as well as greater use of...

This is correct. In this case it means..

```
This includes:
A) efforts to harmonize:
        1) international regulation of
        2) the acceptance of non-U.S comparator products.
B) greater use of real world-data...
```

Basically it means that it includes {the efforts to harmonize (*A* and *B*), as well as *C*}

In the case below ( and to answer your last question about putting 3 nouns in parallel)

> This includes (1) efforts to harmonize international regulations... (2) and the acceptance, (3) as well as greater use of...?

It would've been written like this:

> This includes efforts to harmonize international regulation of biosimilars, the acceptance of non-U.S. comparator products, **and** as well as greater use of real-world data supporting regulatory decision making related to biosimilars.

The usage of comma, would be appropriate after the first item.